# Socket IO not working Android 8.0 due to SELinux

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io, selinux

I'm getting an error when using socketIO on Android

```
W/TcmReceiver: type=1400 audit(0.0:136495): avc: denied { write } for name="tcm" dev="tmpfs" ino=30445 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c242,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:dpmtcm_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
```

Android Code:

```
socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.101:3000");
socket.connect();
```

After some research it seems to be related to access permission with the SELinux enforcement in Android. This causes the underlying socket in the SocketIO library to not be able to open or read.

As a note
I do have the Internet permissions enabled. So that does nos seem to be the problem

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: Could you detail some of the research you mentioned? This doesn't sound right.

Comment: Further evidence: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779971/android-java-socket-io-is-not-emitting-any-events-to-nodejs-server). If you run Wireshark on your server, what can you see?

Answer (score 0):

The only known solution is to disable it or rebuild the ROM after have whitelisted your App to allow access to "IO.socket" (that whitelist file cannot be modified AFTER a build action)

Comment: Does this means that no apps can be build now using any kind of direct socket manipulation?. My idea was to send messages to a server using a TCP socket to reduce http procession and payload. The app works pretty much with real time data. Is this no longer possible in an Android App?